# How to read just the first two numbers ? python +UART

Tags: python, c, uart

I want to make communication between my laptop and my module. For that I create a python file which will send some packets to the UART, which it must read them. 
I have a python script (laptop) that creates a packet:

```
SOF= '24'
SEND_PLAINTEXT= '72'
SEND_KEY  ='73'
RECEIVE_CIPHERTEXT='74'
SIZE_OF_FRAME= '10'
for a in range (0,1):

   line_array=lines[a]
   plaintxt_16b=line_array[0:32]
   plaintext= '24'+'72'+'32'+plaintxt_16b
   ser.write (plaintext.encode())
```

The final  packet is `247232ccddeeff8899aabb4455667700112233`

UART read the packet by using these lines of code in c:

```
uint8_t rx_buffer[38];
int rx_length = dev_uart_ptr->uart_read(rx_buffer, 38);

if (rx_length <38)
{
    printf( rx_buffer);
}
```

I need to read just the two first numbers in order to test if it is the start of the frame or not. Thus, I have changed my code:

```
uint8_t rx_buffer[2];
int rx_length = dev_uart_ptr->uart_read(rx_buffer,2);

if (rx_length <2)
{
    printf( rx_buffer);
}
```

The problem is that numbers which are displayed are `33`, despite I want to read  `24`, I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: What does the uart_read() function do?? Which libraries are you importing for doing this task?

Comment: It just allow reading from the UART,

Comment: Your post is very confusing. At first I thought it was Python code, but it seems that is C/C++ code. Are you executing it at the other side of the channel, aren't you? If so, you should change the labels of the post and set them to C/C++, as this is not a Python question

Comment: int32_t (*uart_read) (void *data, uint16_t len); /*!< read data from uart device(blocked) */

Comment: I am not confusing. I am trying to make communication between my module and my laptop.

Comment: You have posted 2 different scripts. You should clarify where is being executed each one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `plaintext= '24'+'72'+'32'+plaintxt_16b` seems to be executed from right to left. So the first thing in the buffer will be `plaintxt_16b`, then the rest.

The order of the bytes are also from right to left in the packet `247232ccddeeff8899aabb4455667700112233`. So the first byte (index of `0`) is `0x33`

```
18.| 17.| 16.| 15.| 14.| 13.| 12.| 11.| 10.| 9. | 8. | 7. | 6. | 5. | 4. | 3. | 2. | 1. | 0.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
24 | 72 | 32 | cc | dd | ee | ff | 88 | 99 | aa | bb | 44 | 55 | 66 | 77 | 00 | 11 | 22 | 33
```

Try the following:

```
plaintext= plaintxt_16b + '32' + '72' + '24'
```

and leave the UART code the same.

Comment: @Bence  Kaulis, your answer gives me the correct solution, but, I don't how could i use the hexadecimal format in c, the way that you describe in that table. could explain for me please?

Comment: @tssmokey46 Please ask one problem/question and if it is solved do not move to a next one. Open a new question for your next problem, and maybe refer to this one. So please post a new question and elaborate exactly what do you want to do with hexadecimal values in C. Hint: If you only want to compare `if(rx_buffer[0] == 0x24)`.

Comment: I am new in this group, I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you to check endianness of UART.

I think you need to read last 2 tokens, not first 2 tokens.

**EDIT:**

As far as I understand, your UART module is sending data by starting from the end of your packet. Therefore, when you try to read first two numbers, you get `33` but you should read the last two numbers to get `24`.

Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Since @Jalo insisted so much for the full answer here it goes:

As I mentioned above, you need to read last two numbers. You can achieve that by reversing your input by changing `plaintext= '24'+'72'+'32'+plaintxt_16b` to `plaintext = plaintxt_16b + '32' + '72' + '24'`

Comment: I don't understand, could you give ore explanation please.

Comment: Add a full answer, not a suggestion

Comment: @Jalo Endianness seems to be the problem, it is pretty cleat that the other end of the array is transmitted. The rest is quite  straigthforward, so this answer is useful no need to downvote just because it is short.

Comment: @user2390668, my uart module receie data, it must know which is the star of the frame.

Comment: I think that is the kind of content that should go in the comments. You are not solving the problem, just adding indications.

Comment: @BenceKaulics it is straightforward for you, but probably not for him or other people. If that is already answered in another post, a flag can be raised indicating it. If not, an answer should provide the steps necessary to solve the OP question.

Comment: @Jalo Raise your flag then, but the answer still useful and if you feel it should be elaborated leave a comment as you did and post your answer with more detail. Describig endianess in this answer would be too long by the way for on SO answer, so the OP should do some research on her/his own. Note that new users cannot leave comments.

Comment: @BenceKaulics the OP has a concrete code problem. A valid answer "for me" should include the correct way of doing it and a brief explanation. Mostly any question in SO can be answered with a full encyclopedia, but obviously that is not the goal. Instead, working and practical solutions for the questions should be the target. I would also like to add that is my opinion and why I downvoted, which is my choice. Anyway, I will gladly read any other argument you have and the person who answered can improve his post and then I will reconsider my vote ;)

Comment: @Jalo "give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime"

Comment: @Jalo IMO This answer was not that bad to be downvoted, yes it could have more detail but still it **added value**. There are far worse answers from new users, consider that as well.